# Can't get image to align to bottom of div with Foundation block-grid class

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4.0 framework, and I have a block grid I am trying to create.  Each `li` contains an image with a fixed width but the height is not the same for all images.  I need the images and text to align to the bottom of the div.  Below is my html.  I have tried changing the parent div to position relative and position absolute, but cannot get anything to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 127px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
}

// All other styles are defined by the ul.large-block-grid-4 within Foundation.
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-shadow-wrapper">
  <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <img class="cover" src="image1.png">
        <p>Book 1 Title</p>
        <p>Some Cool Author</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <img class="cover" src="image2.png">
        <p>Book 2 Title</p>
        <p>Some Cool Author</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <img class="cover" src="image3.png">
        <p>Book 3 Title</p>
        <p>Some Cool Author</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <img class="cover" src="image4.png">
        <p>Book 4 Title</p>
        <p>Some Cool Author</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your css code, how can without css your solution yo got it?

Comment: `<a><h5></h5></a>` is not W3C valid

Comment: I am using the Foundation base styles that they apply for their `ul.large-block-grid-4` class.  I tried applying `l1 { display:inline-block; }` with no luck.  I will be honest, I am not a front end guy (hence the W3C invalid html).  Just a backend guy trying to fix a problem.

Comment: You should clear the float of the li element too. "float: none;"

Comment: Adding float:none does solve the issue when viewing on a large screen, but then it does not collapses with the responsive grid on smaller screens. The items overlay each other. Any suggestion for this? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by adding `float:none` to the `li` in my css.  This aligned everything, but when reducing the browser size, my images were stacking on top of each other.  I then added a `div` inside the `<li>` and it seemed to then collapse correctly.

Corrected CSS:

```
li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Corrected HTML:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <a href="http://example.com">
      <img class="cover" src="image4.png">
      <p>Book 4 Title</p>
      <p>Some Cool Author</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```