# Middle vertical align for images in Foundation block grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 for the first time to build a friend's small picture folio site.

Testing @ http://wagonbroadcastservice.org/ktest/

The layout is meant to be quite simple: a grid of images. Using "block grid" seemed appropriate, but the problem that I've run into is that I need each image to be vertically aligned to the middle, rather than the top of each row. I'm having issues figuring out what code I need for that.

I came across one thread that I thought might have answered my questions, but the proposed answer doesn't seem to work at all.
[Can't get image to align to bottom of div with Foundation block-grid class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030472/cant-get-image-to-align-to-bottom-of-div-with-foundation-block-grid-class)

Does anybody have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual "problem" is caused by this style rule (in app.css line 1123):

`[class*="block-grid-"] > li {

    display: inline;

    float: left;

    height: auto;

    padding: 0 0.625em 1.25em;
}`

You can test it by changing the rule-set to:

`[class*="block-grid-"] > li {

    display: inline-block;

    height: auto;

    padding: 0 0.625em 1.25em;
}`

`inline-block` has some other drawbacks, like the white-space issue. There are 2 options to avoid the unwanted margins between the elements:
1. remove any white-space and line breaks from your HTML markup
2. set the font-size of the parent element to '0'

Using Frameworks isn't always the best/ easiest solution! ;-)
And as I don't know "Zurb Foundation 4" I cannot help you more - sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. It works pretty well. I needed to also adjust the percentage "in.large-block-grid-3 > li", but that's fixed it. Cheers!

Comment: I've just noticed that "inline-block" actually kills the responsiveness of the grid specifically for Firefox. I'm not sure why. Once you get to the breakpoint on FF, the images won't continue to shrink down to mobile, like it would on Safari or Chrome.

FYI for readers!

Comment: Try removing the `display: inline-block;` from `[class*="block-grid-"]` in line 1107. And add `max-width: 100%;` to `[class*="block-grid-"] > li` in line 1123.